# Why is multicol adding a blank page?

Tags: page-breaking

I'm formatting a word list for a small pamphlet about [Diceware](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diceware).

After tweaking the page layout and multicol environment so that the pages themselves look satisfactory, an extra page is mysteriously added.

Here is an example which demonstrates the problem:

```
\documentclass[9pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{multicol}
\setstocksize{5in}{3.5in}
\settrimmedsize{5in}{3.5in}{*}
\settrims{0in}{0in}

\setlrmarginsandblock{.2in}{.2in}{*}
\setulmarginsandblock{0.2in}{.5in}{*}
\setheadfoot{1em}{1.5em}
\setheaderspaces{0in}{*}{*}
\checkandfixthelayout

\copypagestyle{wordlist}{plain}
\makeoddfoot{wordlist}{}{}{}
\makeevenfoot{wordlist}{}{}{}

\begin{document}

\changepage{.4in}{}{}{}{}{}{}{-0.15in}{}
\pagestyle{wordlist}

\fontsize{4}{4.2}\selectfont

\begin{multicols*}{4}
\noindent
5411 ritzy \\
5412 riverboat \\
5413 roamer \\
5414 robe \\
5415 rocket \\
5416 romancer \\
5421 ropelike \\
5422 rotisserie \\
5423 roundtable \\
5424 royal \\
5425 rubber \\
5426 rudderless \\
5431 rugby \\
5432 ruined \\
5433 rulebook \\
5434 rummage \\
5435 running \\
5436 rupture \\
5441 rustproof \\
5442 sabotage \\
5443 sacrifice \\
5444 saddlebag \\
5445 saffron \\
5446 sainthood \\
5451 saltshaker \\
5452 samurai \\
5453 sandworm \\
5454 sapphire \\
5455 sardine \\
5456 sassy \\
5461 satchel \\
5462 sauna \\
5463 savage \\
5464 saxophone \\
5465 scarf \\
5466 scenario \\
5511 schoolbook \\
5512 scientist \\
5513 scooter \\
5514 scrapbook \\
5515 sculpture \\
5516 scythe \\
5521 secretary \\
5522 sedative \\
5523 segregator \\
5524 seismology \\
5525 selected \\
5526 semicolon \\
5531 senator \\
5532 septum \\
5533 sequence \\
5534 serpent \\
5535 sesame \\
5536 settler \\
5541 severely \\
5542 shack \\
5543 shelf \\
5544 shirt \\
5545 shovel \\
5546 shrimp \\
5551 shuttle \\
5552 shyness \\
5553 siamese \\
5554 sibling \\
5555 siesta \\
5556 silicon \\
5561 simmering \\
5562 singles \\
5563 sisterhood \\
5564 sitcom \\
5565 sixfold \\
5566 sizable \\
5611 skateboard \\
5612 skeleton \\
5613 skies \\
5614 skulk \\
5615 skylight \\
5616 slapping \\
5621 sled \\
5622 slingshot \\
5623 sloth \\
5624 slumbering \\
5625 smartphone \\
5626 smelliness \\
5631 smitten \\
5632 smokestack \\
5633 smudge \\
5634 snapshot \\
5635 sneezing \\
5636 sniff \\
5641 snowsuit \\
5642 snugness \\
5643 speakers \\
5644 sphinx \\
5645 spider \\
5646 splashing \\
5651 sponge \\
5652 sprout \\
5653 spur \\
5654 spyglass \\
5655 squirrel \\
5656 statue \\
5661 steamboat \\
5662 stingray \\
5663 stopwatch \\
5664 strawberry \\
5665 student \\
5666 stylus \\
6111 suave \\
6112 subway \\
6113 suction \\
6114 suds \\
6115 suffocate \\
6116 sugar \\
6121 suitcase \\
6122 sulphur \\
6123 superstore \\
6124 surfer \\
6125 sushi \\
6126 swan \\
6131 sweatshirt \\
6132 swimwear \\
6133 sword \\
6134 sycamore \\
6135 syllable \\
6136 symphony \\
6141 synagogue \\
6142 syringes \\
6143 systemize \\
6144 tablespoon \\
6145 taco \\
6146 tadpole \\
6151 taekwondo \\
6152 tagalong \\
6153 takeout \\
6154 tallness \\
6155 tamale \\
6156 tanned \\
6161 tapestry \\
6162 tarantula \\
6163 tastebud \\
6164 tattoo \\
6165 tavern \\
6166 thaw \\
6211 theater \\
6212 thimble \\
6213 thorn \\
6214 throat \\
6215 thumb \\
6216 thwarting \\
6221 tiara \\
6222 tidbit \\
6223 tiebreaker \\
6224 tiger \\
6225 timid \\
6226 tinsel \\
6231 tiptoeing \\
6232 tirade \\
6233 tissue \\
6234 tractor \\
6235 tree \\
6236 tripod \\
6241 trousers \\
6242 trucks \\
6243 tryout \\
6244 tubeless \\
6245 tuesday \\
6246 tugboat \\
6251 tulip \\
6252 tumbleweed \\
6253 tupperware \\
6254 turtle \\
6255 tusk \\
6256 tutorial \\
6261 tuxedo \\
6262 tweezers \\
6263 twins \\
6264 tyrannical \\
6265 ultrasound \\
6266 umbrella \\
6311 umpire \\
6312 unarmored \\
6313 unbuttoned \\
6314 uncle \\
6315 underwear \\
6316 unevenness \\
6321 unflavored \\
6322 ungloved \\
6323 unhinge \\
6324 unicycle \\
6325 unjustly \\
6326 unknown \\
6331 unlocking \\
6332 unmarked \\
6333 unnoticed \\
6334 unopened \\
6335 unpaved \\
6336 unquenched \\
6341 unroll \\
6342 unscrewing \\
6343 untied \\
6344 unusual \\
6345 unveiled \\
6346 unwrinkled \\
6351 unyielding \\
6352 unzip \\
6353 upbeat \\
6354 upcountry \\
6355 update \\
6356 upfront \\
6361 upgrade \\
6362 upholstery \\
6363 upkeep \\
6364 upload \\
6365 uppercut \\
6366 upright \\
6411 upstairs \\
6412 uptown \\
6413 upwind \\
6414 uranium \\
6415 urban \\
6416 urchin \\
6421 urethane \\
6422 urgent \\
6423 urologist \\
6424 username \\
6425 usher \\
6426 utensil \\
6431 utility \\
6432 utmost \\
6433 utopia \\
6434 utterance \\
6435 vacuum \\
6436 vagrancy \\
6441 valuables \\
6442 vanquished \\
6443 vaporizer \\
6444 varied \\
6445 vaseline \\
6446 vegetable \\
6451 vehicle \\
6452 velcro \\
6453 vendor \\
6454 vertebrae \\
6455 vestibule \\
6456 veteran \\
6461 vexingly \\
6462 vicinity \\
6463 videogame \\
6464 viewfinder \\
6465 vigilante \\
6466 village \\
6511 vinegar \\
6512 violin \\
6513 viperfish \\
6514 virus \\
6515 visor \\
6516 vitamins \\
6521 vivacious \\
6522 vixen \\
6523 vocalist \\
6524 vogue \\
6525 voicemail \\
6526 volleyball \\
6531 voucher \\
6532 voyage \\
6533 vulnerable \\
6534 waffle \\
6535 wagon \\
6536 wakeup \\
6541 walrus \\
6542 wanderer \\
6543 wasp \\
6544 water \\
6545 waving \\
6546 wheat \\
6551 whisper \\
6552 wholesaler \\
6553 wick \\
6554 widow \\
6555 wielder \\
6556 wifeless \\
6561 wikipedia \\
6562 wildcat \\
6563 windmill \\
6564 wipeout \\
6565 wired \\
6566 wishbone \\
6611 wizardry \\
6612 wobbliness \\
6613 wolverine \\
6614 womb \\
6615 woolworker \\
6616 workbasket \\
6621 wound \\
6622 wrangle \\
6623 wreckage \\
6624 wristwatch \\
6625 wrongdoing \\
6626 xerox \\
6631 xylophone \\
6632 yacht \\
6633 yahoo \\
6634 yard \\
6635 yearbook \\
6636 yesterday \\
6641 yiddish \\
6642 yield \\
6643 yoyo \\
6644 yodel \\
6645 yogurt \\
6646 yuppie \\
6651 zealot \\
6652 zebra \\
6653 zeppelin \\
6654 zestfully \\
6655 zigzagged \\
6656 zillion \\
6661 zipping \\
6662 zirconium \\
6663 zodiac \\
6664 zombie \\
6665 zookeeper \\
6666 zucchini \\
\end{multicols*}

\end{document}
```

Here is a public ShareLaTeX project containing the example code: https://www.sharelatex.com/project/588788fcfc7a22f64586a859

Why is this page added, and how can I eliminate it without destroying the layout?

For context, these word list pages are an appendix of a longer pamphlet and are intended to be viewed through a magnifier.

I've tried using lua-visual-debug, but don't understand the markings well enough to determine the cause.

Comment: the example doesn't demonstrate anything if it can not be run

Comment: It relies on a large table of data that is too big to post here. The ShareLaTeX page is the example you can run. Edit: Ah, I see you found it. Thank you for your help, I didn't even think to check there!

Comment: You _could_ have posted a smaller example for example if you'd tried to make a page with just one page of text and one blank you'd have noticed straight away that the blank only happened if the previous page was exactly full. Note this question (and its answer) are archived forever but the sharelatex project is typically transient so external links are bad for this site.

Comment: I have done this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

delete the `\\` at the end so your file ends

```
6666 zucchini
```

otherwise you force one white line which in this case spills over and forces an extra page.

Comment: note that you are typesetting the entire file as a single paragraph, it would be much easier for tex if you used a blank line instead or equivalently put `\let\\\=\par` before inputting the file, either would avoid the problem of a trailing `\\ `